# Reading 3 digits string numbers to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, arraylist, casting

I am reading values from a text files as shown below:

```
000,050,007
059,000,157
002,038,000
```

I get a line in the following block:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); // 000,050,007
    List<Integer> list = List.of(Integer.parseInt(line))
}
```

However, I cannot cast the 3 digit values (string) to Integer. So, how can I do this in an elegant way?

**Update:** I use the following approach, but I am not sure if there is a better way than using `map()` 2 times?

```
List<Integer> items= Stream.of(line.split(","))
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .map(Integer::parseInt)
                        .toList();
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for help. But actually I have never seen 2 map in the same stream and it sounds a little bit weird :) So, there is not a better way to use 2 methods in a single map method via method reference, right?

Comment: you haven't seen many streams, then ;-) Chaining `map` calls is fine. Actually if you are already using streams, you might be interested in [Files.lines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)), which returns a stream of lines (i.e. could replace your `while` loop).

Comment: haha, yes you right :)) Actually, I have look at many examples to improve my knowledge on Streams, but could not find a comprehensive examples. So, would you suggest any tutorial or article for Java Stream with s-examples please? Many thanks.

Comment: Naming is hard, it always depends on context/domain. I suppose this is from a math problem/algorithm? In that case, it will depend on whether there are any `x` variables nearby that could lead to confusion, e.g. `ax` might be mistaken for "a * x", or for "x component of vector a". In case of doubt, use longer, more descriptive names rather than the sometimes extreme brevity of mathematical symbols. As for tutorials, there is always the [official oracle tutorial on streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the line on comma before converting it to List of integers

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); // 000,050,007
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
        .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.trim()))
        .toList();
    list.add(integers);
}
```

Note that having multiple `map` calls doesn't affect the performance, you just need to decide based on readability here.

As you are using `BufferedReader`, you can replace `while` loop with stream

```
List<List<Integer>> list = reader.lines().map(line ->
    Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
        .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.trim()))
        .toList()
).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks, just seen your answer after adding an update. I am wondering if I also want to use `.map(String::trim)` before `.map(Integer::parseInt)`, then how should I use it? Could you see my update?

Comment: updated the answer as per updated question

Answer (score 2):

A `Scanner` is possible too:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class NScan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(args[0]))).useDelimiter("[\r\n,]")) {
            List<Integer> ints = s.tokens().
                map(String::trim).
                map(Integer::valueOf).
                toList();
            System.out.println(ints);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```